# Getting Unexpected result with 'sizeof(union.variable)'->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am getting unexpected result for the below code.

```
union
{
    int aBuf[RMH_MAX_UNENCODED_LENGTH+sizeof(MSG_INFO)]; //4070+68=4138
}sUnion;
NSLog(@"%d",sizeof(sUnion.aBuf));//printing as 16552 and not 4138
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct output for this code. Your union contains an array of 4138 `int` types. If you ran `NSLog(@"%d",sizeof(int));`, the output would be `4`. 4*4138=16552, so an array of 4138 `int`s is 16552 bytes long.

Comment: Thanks. I forget to calculate that.